# How to change table structure in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that has columns like:

```
a|b|c|d|e
```

and rows like:

```
1|3|5|7|9
2|4|6|8|10
```

How to change it to:

```
Char|Num|
a|1
a|2
b|3
b|4
c|5
c|6
d|7
d|8
e|9
e|10
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use PROC TRANSPOSE.  The only gotcha is to get what you want you need a BY variable.  Easiest thing is to add a record number and use that as your BY.

```
data have;
input a b c d;
i = _n_;
datalines;
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want(drop=i);
by i;
var a b c d;
run;
```